# Query SQL Server using session variable

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to query a SQL Server database table based on a user variable (using ASP.NET and C#). I want to be able to pull just the user's unique records from the Waste Application Information table where the Farm Owner name is equal to the variable name (which is a string).

Here's part of my code:

```
conn.Open();
WasteAppData = "SELECT * FROM [WASTE APPLICATION INFORMATION] WHERE [FARM OWNER] = (user variable) ";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(WasteAppData, conn);

GridView1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If I replace the "(user variable)" with the actual value in the table column it does work correctly. Like this: 'Joe Smith' I've tried referencing the variable which is pulled from another webform with no luck... I think my syntax is incorrect? Any help would be great!

Comment: `I've tried referencing the variable` there's no such feature in .NET which means you tried to concatenate or inject the string in a SQL injection bug. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: You say "*I've tried referencing the variable ... but that didn't work*."  Show us *that* code.

Comment: Also, give us the specific error message and/or behavior.  There are many things that can cause a client-server database query to fail, so just saying that it didn't work isn't usually enough to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
WasteAppData = "SELECT * FROM [WASTE APPLICATION INFORMATION] WHERE [FARM OWNER] = @FarmOwn";
using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(WasteAppData , conn)
 {
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FarmOwn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = strFarmOwnwer;
    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

In this case "strFarmOwner" would be replaced with your actual variable that holds the value you want.

Comment: Albert, That got me fixed!  I really do appreciate it!  I had a few other issues which I figured out as well...missing Namespaces, etc.  This is the first day that I've used stackoverflow so I'm 1/1! Pretty good average. Have a great day!